# in operator, float("NaN") and np.nan

Tags: python, numpy, containers, nan

I used to believe that `in` operator in Python checks the presence of element in some collection using equality checking `==`, so `element in some_list` is roughly equivalent to `any(x == element for x in some_list)`. For example:

```
True in [1, 2, 3]
# True because True == 1
```

or

```
1 in [1., 2., 3.]
# also True because 1 == 1.
```

However, it is well-known that `NaN` is not equal to itself. So I expected that `float("NaN") in [float("NaN")]` is `False`. And it is `False` indeed.

However, if we use `numpy.nan` instead of `float("NaN")`, the situation is quite different:

```
import numpy as np
np.nan in [np.nan, 1, 2]
# True
```

But `np.nan == np.nan` still gives `False`!

How is it possible? What's the difference between `np.nan` and `float("NaN")`? How does `in` deal with `np.nan`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To check if the item is in the list, Python tests for object identity *first*, and then tests for equality only if the objects are different.<sup>1</sup>

`float("NaN") in [float("NaN")]` is False because two *different* `NaN`  objects are involved in the comparison. The test for identity therefore returns False, and then the test for equality also returns False since `NaN != NaN`.

`np.nan in [np.nan, 1, 2]` however is True because the *same* `NaN` object is involved in the comparison. The test for object identity returns True and so Python immediately recognises the item as being in the list.

The `__contains__` method (invoked using `in`) for many of Python's other builtin Container types, such as tuples and sets, is implemented using the same check.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least this is true in CPython. Object identity here means that the objects are found at the same memory address: the [contains method for lists](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L397-L407) is performed using [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L710-L736) which quickly compares object pointers before a potentially more complicated object comparison. Other Python implementations may differ.

Comment: Yupp. `nan = float("NaN"); nan in [nan]` gives `True`. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any benefit of doing this (first identity then equality). Why not check equality directly? I am asking this because I always thought nan is the only object for which x is x holds true but x!=x. Seeing this I am wondering if there are others?

Comment: @ayhan - Checking identity is a relatively cheap operation (just compare memory addresses). Checking equality may be arbitrarily expensive.

Comment: @John A professor of mine used to say if it doesn't have to be correct I can make it arbitrarily fast. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) says for `x in s`: `True if an item of s is equal to x, else False`. Seems like a bug - whether documentation or implementation is up for debate. Considering the consequences, it should probably just be documented what the `in` operator actually does.

Comment: @Voo since `nan` is the only thing that breaks this it is apparently not considered important enough. See the  [rejection notice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/#rejection-notice) to PEP 754 _This PEP has been rejected. After sitting open for four years, it has failed to generate sufficient community interest._

Comment: @Paul It would also happen for any custom class that defines a weird equality operator I'd think, but I agree that it's a problem that probably only comes up with nan in practice.

Answer (score 6):

One thing worth mentioning is that numpy arrays do behave as expected:

```
a = np.array((np.nan,))
a[0] in a
# False
```

Variations of the theme:

```
[np.nan]==[np.nan]
# True
[float('nan')]==[float('nan')]
# False
{np.nan: 0}[np.nan]
# 0
{float('nan'): 0}[float('nan')]
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# KeyError: nan
```

Everything else is covered in @AlexRiley's excellent answer.

Comment: Interseting, that it works as expected even for `dtype=object`.

Comment: `in` for NumPy arrays is [implemented](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L28-L46) as `(array == item).any()` as your answer shows. I guess the developers were forced to chose this approach since NumPy arrays are not internally collections of references to objects and so ids cannot be compared.

Comment: Yep, numpy appears to always compare by value: `a = np.array([None,[np.nan]]); a[1] in a` is also `False`.

Comment: @AlexRiley actually, in the example I just gave we have `a[1] == [np.nan]` -> `True` but `a == [np.nan]` -> `array([False, False], dtype=bool)` which I do find puzzling. Can you explain that?

Comment: I think it's because with `a[1] == [np.nan]` we are comparing two lists that contain the same NaN object and the list equality check uses `PyObject_RichCompareBool` to compare items (so ids are checked). For `a == [np.nan]`, it is the NumPy array's equality method is called and this method does not (or cannot) check ids of values so `a[1]` and `[np.nan]` are not seen as equal. (I believe the code for object arrays that is executed is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L1174-L1208)).

Comment: Wow. `[np.nan]==[np.nan]` is quite surprising as well.

Comment: Ilya, @AlexRiley actually, I think I know what's going on and I think it's a genuine bug not related to `nan`. The problem is with the implementation of `__contains__` you mention above. If `item` happens to be a list it is broadcast. As a consequence `[5] in np.array([None, 4, [5]])` -> `False` and `[5] in np.array([None, 5, [4]])` -> `True`!

Comment: @PaulPanzer, Hmm… I still don't understand why `[5] in np.array([None, 4, [5]])` is `False` and `[5] in np.array([None, 5, [4]])`. (Probably, we should open another question.)

Comment: As I said I think it's a bug. When arr==item is evaluated (item being [5]) then [5] is broadcast to something like (conceptually) [5, 5, 5] so the list-ness is lost in translation. I've opened an issue at the numpy tracker.