# Pandas/Numpy NaN None comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan, nonetype

In Python Pandas and Numpy, why is the comparison result different?

```
from pandas import Series
from numpy import NaN
```

`NaN` is not equal to `NaN`

```
>>> NaN == NaN
False
```

but `NaN` inside a list or tuple is

```
>>> [NaN] == [NaN], (NaN,) == (NaN,)
(True, True)
```

While `Series` with `NaN` are not equal again:

```
>>> Series([NaN]) == Series([NaN])
0    False
dtype: bool
```

And `None`:

```
>>> None == None, [None] == [None]
(True, True)
```

While

```
>>> Series([None]) == Series([None])
0    False
dtype: bool
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) explains the reasons for `NaN == NaN` being `False` in general, but does not explain its behaviour in python/pandas collections.

Comment: I don't think that linked post gives the answer relevant to innerworkings of `np.NaN` in python collections. If `NaN!=NaN`, why `[NaN]==[NaN]` in python?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721635/in-operator-floatnan-and-np-nan) and in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#id12) to check sequence equality

> element identity is compared first, and element comparison is
>   performed only for distinct elements.

Because `np.nan` and `np.NaN` refer to the same object i.e. `(np.nan is np.nan is np.NaN) == True` this equality holds `[np.nan] == [np.nan]`, but on the other hand `float('nan')` function creates a new object on every call so `[float('nan')] == [float('nan')]` is `False`.

Pandas/Numpy do not have this problem:

```
>>> pd.Series([np.NaN]).eq(pd.Series([np.NaN]))[0], (pd.Series([np.NaN]) == pd.Series([np.NaN]))[0]
(False, False)
```

Although special [equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) method treats `NaN`s in the same location as equals.

```
>>> pd.Series([np.NaN]).equals(pd.Series([np.NaN]))
True
```

`None` is treated differently. `numpy` considers them equal:

```
>>> pd.Series([None, None]).values == (pd.Series([None, None])).values
array([ True,  True])
```

While `pandas` does not

```
>>> pd.Series([None, None]) == (pd.Series([None, None]))
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Also there is an inconsistency between `==` operator and `eq` method, which is discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20442):

```
>>> pd.Series([None, None]).eq(pd.Series([None, None]))
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Tested on    `pandas: 0.23.4 numpy: 1.15.0`