# Unexpected behavior when applying function to all columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble making sense of why a call to pandas' dataframe.apply method is not returning the expected result. Could someone please shed some light on why the first call to apply shown below doesn't return an expected result, while the second one does?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, np.nan],
    "y": ["hi", "there", np.nan]
})
print(df)
#>      x      y
#> 0  1.0     hi
#> 1  2.0  there
#> 2  NaN    NaN
print(df.dtypes)
#> x    float64
#> y     object
#> dtype: object

# why would something like this not return the expected result (which should
# be TRUE, FALSE):
print(df.apply(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.number)))
#> x    False
#> y    False
#> dtype: bool

# but something like this returns the expected result (i.e., median imputation
# is used if the series is a number, otherwise NULLs are replaced with "MISSING"):
def replace_nulls(s):
    is_numeric = np.issubdtype(s, np.number)
    missing_value = s.median() if is_numeric else "MISSING"
    return np.where(s.isnull(), missing_value, s)

print(df.apply(replace_nulls))
#>      x        y
#> 0  1.0       hi
#> 1  2.0    there
#> 2  1.5  MISSING
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-03 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

Comment: That seems broken to me.  `pd.Series({k: np.issubdtype(v, np.number) for k, v in df.items()})` works but your's doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, not sure why a comprehension like that would work where apply doesn't.

Comment: `apply` does a lot of checking and things that make it safe.  This is a bug and I don't have the patience to unwind it at the moment.  The comprehension is exactly what it seems to be and therefore no surprises.  Let me know if you want to submit a bug report.  Otherwise, I will.

Comment: I'll submit a bug report, thanks. I'm seeing somre more weirdness that may add to the story.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28773

Comment: As of pandas 1.3.4, this works as OP intended.

Comment: Is this thread helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436356/pandas-numpy-nan-none-comparison

Answer (score 0):

The confusion arises from a misunderstanding about what is passed to the function in `DataFrame.apply` and how `np.issubdtype` is used.

- `DataFrame.apply` passes each column as a pandas Series to the `lambda` function, not the `dtype` of the column directly.
- `np.issubdtype` expects two arguments: a `dtype` and a type or tuple of types to check against.

But when you pass a Series (which `x` is) to `np.issubdtype`, it is not the correct usage, because `np.issubdtype` is designed to work with `dtypes`, not with Series objects directly. That's why it returns False for both columns.

You shoud do this instead

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, np.nan],
    "y": ["hi", "there", np.nan]
})
print(df.apply(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.number)))
```

which gives

```
x     True
y    False
dtype: bool
```

That means that the correct way to use things in your first case is:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number)))
```

which gives what you had above.

This is actually what you did in your second case using it as

```
def replace_nulls(s):
    is_numeric = np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.number)  # Correctly checks the dtype of the Series
    missing_value = s.median() if is_numeric else "MISSING"
    return np.where(s.isnull(), missing_value, s)
```