# Handling NaN Values in Pandas with Conditional Statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with some data where the customer postcode data is invalid. As a result I'm not able to map the CountryISOCode to their postcode resulting in a NaN. However, I have noticed that for all CountryISOCodes with NaN, the CurrencyCode can provide me with enough to fix the problem for now.

I've gone to various Stackoverflow articles but I cannot find the solution to my problem. I've tried...

```
def func(row):
    if row['CountryISOCode'] == np.nan & row['Currency'] == 'EUR':
        return 'IRE'
elif row['CountryISOCode'] == np.nan & row['Currency'] == 'GBP':
    return 'GBR'
else:
    return row['CountryISOCode']

df['CountryISOCode'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

and some other methods but to no avail...

Below I have provided a replication of the data I'm working with

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['Steve', 'Invalid Postcode', 'GBP', np.nan ],
    ['Robyn', 'Invalid Postcode', 'EUR', np.nan],
    ['James', 'Valid Postcode', 'GBP', 'GBR'],
    ['Halo', 'Invalid Postcode', 'EUR', np.nan],
    ['Jesus', 'Valid Postcode', 'GBP', 'GBR']
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "PostCode", "CurrencyCode", "CountryISOCode"], data=data)
```

Essentially if I was working with SQL my code would be as follows.

```
IF countryISOCode IS NULL 
    AND currency = ‘GBP’ 
THEN CountryISOCode =  ‘GBR’
ELSE
IF countryISOCode IS NULL 
    AND currency = ‘EUR 
THEN CountryISOCode =  ‘IRE’
ELSE countryISOCode 
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing `&` to `and`?  There is a difference in the two and I think you want to use `and` here.  You can see more about the difference here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i]

Comment: The code runs with `and` but doesn't seem to fix the problem. The data just remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with a dictionary specifying mappings for when currency code is helpful:

```
cmap = {'GBP': 'GBR', 'EUR': 'IRE'}
df['CountryISOCode'] = df['CountryISOCode'].fillna(df['CurrencyCode'].map(cmap))

print(df)

    Name          PostCode CurrencyCode CountryISOCode
0  Steve  Invalid Postcode          GBP            GBR
1  Robyn  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
2  James    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
3   Halo  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
4  Jesus    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
```

Comment: This solution has fixed my problem in the simplest manner... One minor change is that it should be `cmap = {'GBP': 'GBR', 'EUR': 'IRE'}`

Answer (score 4):

I am adding this answer as it adds value to the original question.  The reason the comparison statements weren't working is because `np.nan == np.nan` will not work.  You can check for the identity of the NaN element but not equality.  See [in operator, float("NaN") and np.nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721635/in-operator-floatnan-and-np-nan) for more detail.  With that said, this is how you can transform the original code to make it work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                    
import numpy as np

raw_data = [
    ['Steve', 'Invalid Postcode', 'GBP', np.nan ],
    ['Robyn', 'Invalid Postcode', 'EUR', np.nan],
    ['James', 'Valid Postcode', 'GBP', 'GBR'],
    ['Halo', 'Invalid Postcode', 'EUR', np.nan],
    ['Jesus', 'Valid Postcode', 'GBP', 'GBR']
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "PostCode", "Currency", "CountryISOCode"], data=raw_data)

def func(row):
    if row['CountryISOCode'] is np.nan and row['Currency'] == 'EUR':
        return 'IRE'
    elif row['CountryISOCode'] is np.nan and row['Currency'] == 'GBP':
        return 'GBR'
    else:
        return row['CountryISOCode']

df['CountryISOCode'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
```

However, the other answers are great also.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for this, which allows you to choose from a list depending on the result of a list of conditions:

```
m1 = df.CountryISOCode.isna()
m2 = df.CurrencyCode.eq('GBP')
m3 = df.CurrencyCode.eq('EUR')
df.loc[:,'CountryISOCode'] = np.select([m1&m2, m1&m3], ['GBP','IRE'], 
                                       default=df.CountryISOCode)

 Name          PostCode CurrencyCode CountryISOCode
0  Steve  Invalid Postcode          GBP            GBP
1  Robyn  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
2  James    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
3   Halo  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
4  Jesus    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
```

Comment: This sort of works but its filling in a GBP value with IRE which wouldn't work. Index 2

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

use [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions and multiple choices:

```
df['CountryISOCode']=np.select([(df.CurrencyCode=='GBP')&(df.CountryISOCode.isna()),\
                            (df.CurrencyCode=='EUR')&df.CountryISOCode.isna()],['GBR','IRE'],\
                           default=df.CountryISOCode)

    Name          PostCode CurrencyCode CountryISOCode
0  Steve  Invalid Postcode          GBP            GBR
1  Robyn  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
2  James    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
3   Halo  Invalid Postcode          EUR            IRE
4  Jesus    Valid Postcode          GBP            GBR
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer using `np.select` works, my personal favorite is using `mask`:

```
df['CountryISOCode'] = df['CountryISOCode'] \
    .mask(df['CountryISOCode'].isna() & df['Currency'].eq('GBP'), 'GBR') \
    .mask(df['CountryISOCode'].isna() & df['Currency'].eq('EUR'), 'IRE')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!.